# Does Watir-webdriver use goto method? Because url seems to open to data;

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, automation, watir-webdriver

I'm new to to test automation and I'm having an issue getting started. I am using ruby 1.9.3, watir-webdriver 0.9.3, chromedirver 2.24, yosemite osx and sublime 2 / terminal to execute. I am trying to get the method 'goto' to take me to google.com, but i get this error.

```
rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `goto' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

this is my code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'

@Browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome #You can also use firefox
@Browserc.goto("http://google.com")
```

I have tried firefox and it will open to a new tab. I also tried using chrome and the browser open with "data;" in the url. I can't seem to find an answer on SO or Online. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

data; is a default string that is set in the url when the browser starts. Seems that goto method is not found. You might have a config issue.

One possible issue might be that you used @Browserc instead of @Browser when you called goto.

try

```
@Browser.goto("http://google.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is  c next to `@Browser` in your `goto` statement causing the issue. 
What I would suggest is always use something like below .It is not a best practice to use `@Browser` (starts with captial letter).

```
require 'rubygems'

require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome #To open chrome browser

browser = Watir::Browser.new:firefox #To open Firefox browser

browser.goto "http://www.google.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

This fix is for ubuntu:

I uninstalled the chromedriver and downloaded chrome directly from their website. The executable file should be stored in /usr/bin. Finally use the following code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto('google.com')
```

PS: You don't need to use watir-webdriver anymore because watir now includes it in the latest versions. That is why it is not included in this example.